# Protected Archives

Tags: c#, archive, protected

I am tring to develop a MMORPG(masive multiplayer online role-playing game) in C# and i need to find a way to archive the client files. I've searched on the internet a way to create password/key protected archives in C# but i found nothing. So, i come here to ask... is possible to archive files(images, scripts, models, etc...) into one key or password-protected archive that is only unpacked in a temporary folder when the game is launched?

I also looked on this article on wikipedia about an algorithm named [XTEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA):

Comment: http://http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Just go to [Hero Engine](http://www.heroengine.com/) and let them take over.
Or use [Unity 3D](https://unity3d.com/), assets will be handled by their mechanisms.

The best I can tell you is this: don't think you can implement an MMO from scratch. You will have to find and research the correct middleware and stick those pieces together.

Your question clearly reveals that you are far away from even understanding how large scale software like commercial MMOs are produced.

But just to give you an answer: use [Rijndael](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to symmetrically encrypt files. Don't ever store the decrypted files in a temp folder, that doesn't make sense.